# Display text when gif animation ends

Tags: javascript, animation, text, gif

i was searching throught the internet but i didnt find the right answer..
If i have for example:

```
<img src="gif.gif" loop="false" />
```

How to make this div.. to display text after last frame?
Is there any function in Javascript or something like that?
Thank you..

Comment: can you be more specific? what are you using the gif for ? are you showing it while something loads or is it just something that is always on screen?

Comment: Anything more than setting a timer to match the length of the animation? Likely no. I'm pretty sure that the image isn't going to throw any type of event that you can subscribe to, to then act upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the timing of the .gif file down, you will need to use a JavaScript function to display the div on cue.

```
function DisplayDiv(){

    $('#myDiv').addClass('ShowDiv');

}

SetTimeout('DisplayDiv', 1000); // 1000 is milliseconds
```

This is all pseudo-code. It will have to be tweaked to meet your needs and timing. Most likely I'd think you would need the SetTimeout to run on page load.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way of interacting between GIF animation frames and JavaScript.
One suggestion would be to move that animation to canvas.

SetTimeout, as suggested by Joel, is quite unreliable and is browser dependant, AFAIK.